# Residue Theorem on a Complicated Function

Tags: complex-analysis

I am trying to find the analytical Laplace Inverse of the following $F(s)$ using Residue Theorem or any other method existing in the math world

$$\lambda=\frac{Pe}{5\left[1+{Pe}^2\over175\right]}\left[\frac{cosh(\sqrt{s}a)}{cosh(\sqrt{s}a)+\frac{1}{3} \frac{D_m}{D_f}\frac{\phi_m}{\phi_f}\sqrt{s}sinh(\sqrt{s}a)}-7\right]$$

$$\Psi=\frac{1}{\left[1+{Pe}^2\over175\right]}\left[\frac{3cosh(\sqrt{s}a)}{cosh(\sqrt{s}a)+\frac{1}{3} \frac{D_m}{D_f}\frac{\phi_m}{\phi_f}\sqrt{s}sinh(\sqrt{s}a)}-\frac{D_m}{D_f}s-3\right]$$

$$F(s)=\frac{1}{s}\exp\left( \frac{-1}{2}\left[\lambda+\sqrt{\lambda^2-4\Psi}\right]x_D\right)$$

Any variable other than $s$ could be assumed as constant. The numerical Laplace inversion is easy. I am interested in the closed form expression if it can be found. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Set all the constants to $1$. Is your function fast enough decreasing as $\Re(s) \to -\infty$ ?

Comment: The function is okay and numerical Laplace inversion yields sensible results without any need to set any constant to non-physical values. I need to know if any analytical solution exists or should I never mind it.